# Android: Default layout for listitem containing title and subtitle

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, listitem

I have made a listitem, containing a title and a subtitle. Looking to the result, I think it doesn't look really professional. So that's why I'm asking.

The listitem I'm looking for is pretty common (it's used in a lot of apps i.e. Android's default settings menu and it's also shown when you add a listview in the graphical layout editor tab in eclipse).

So my question is: Where can I find a default layout for a listitem with a title and a subtitle?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Resource id is `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`

Upper text line has id `android.R.id.text1` and lower one - `android.R.id.text2`

Layout is located in the `<ANDROID_SDK_ROOT>/platforms/<any_api_level>/data/res/layout` folder

**OR**

You can use `TwoLineListItem` from the default Android controls list(it is located under "Advanced" tab in Eclipse Layout Editor)

**OR**

You can build your own layout with anything you like(for example `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"` and two `TextEdit`s added

Comment: m1shk4 has right, or you can easy make your own custom row ! In 10-20 XML lines it's done !

Answer (score 1):

So The Best Way Is:- I took out the simple list item 2 and made an layout in my project and with little editing it took the same layout as you may give in android.R.simple_list_item_2

So the code is:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:mode="twoLine"
android:paddingStart="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
android:paddingLeft="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
android:paddingEnd="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
android:paddingRight="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight">

<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

<TextView android:id="@id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/text1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />
```